# How can I implement global exception handler in C# test project

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nunit

I'm working on selenium with C# and using NUnit3.0 test framework and I need to implement a global exception handler in my test project, how to do it? any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create you own [Custom exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cdya3t(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
public class CustomSeleniumException: Exception
{
    public CustomSeleniumException()
    {
    }

    public CustomSeleniumException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public CustomSeleniumException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by

> global exception handler

but MSDN gives basic [guide here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(v=vs.110).aspx). IMHO having central place to manage thrown exceptions could be a bad idea. Exceptions are thrown in a certain scope and you need to catch those according to your flow. Sometimes you need to let Exceptions propagate higher up the call chain, rather than handling them right away. You could look at those [Exception patterns](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ExceptionPatterns) before making the final decision. But if you still need such, try this [Global Exception Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/171ezxzc.aspx).